# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 doesn't open .cs files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

After I installed IntelliJ IDEA (Jetbrains) and JDK 1.8.0_102 my Visual Studio isn't able to open .cs Files with my user account. It always show the error message "The document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved.". On rightclick -> "open with" -> "Editor" the file opens in notepad - so there is no security issue.

After I delete any.cs file and undo my pending changes, I can open each .cs file without any problem - but only in the current visual studio session. After reastart VS the problem occurs again.

When I start Visual Studio with another user, there is no such problem!

I tried to repair Visual Studio, I tried to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio and I also tried the VisualStudioUninstaller (which remove all settings in AppData folder) and reinstall Visual Studio again but nothing helps.

I would be very grateful for any ideas.

Edit:

I also tried the flags to reset user settings /ResetSettings and /ResetUserData

When I start with /Save Mode the error message change to "The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070002)".

Comment: Have you tried `Tools | Import and Export Settings... | Reset all settings`? Perhaps you're logged in to Visual Studio so it's restoring your settings from the cloud, even though you deleted the AppData folder. Resetting all settings as above should sort that out.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, i've tried it, but i 've got still the same error.

Comment: I've had a similar problem in the past (I think I was using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013 at the time but it may still apply?), I went into the Default Programs screen in Windows, and changed the default program for .cs files to something else (Notepad). I then rebooted and changed it back to Visual Studio and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you jonc, i have tried this, unfortunately without success. When I open the .cs file from windows explorer, there was no problem. But when I open a project or a solution and I try to open the .cs file from solution explorer, I still get the same error.

Comment: Use [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896645) to determine what file is being looked for by who and why it can't be opened, which may give you a hint as to what's broken. The nuclear option is to completely delete your local profile, make a new one and reinstall VS then, since it works from another user.

Comment: @Jeroen: Thanks, I tried ProcMon (really interesting, I've neve seen this before), but I can't find any hint to fix my problem. The access of devenv.exe to my .cs file has always the result "SUCCESS". I also can't see any difference, when I open the file with another user - what is still working. I would like to delay the nuclear option, to see if someone else have an idea.

Comment: Something *must* fail. Start VS with `/SafeMode` and use Procmon to figure out why that isn't working, because it really *should* work (it's why it's called "safe mode", after all).

Comment: Another idea: look at the length of your `PATH`. If it's exceptionally long, things start mysteriously failing. See if you can trim some fat from it.

Comment: @Jeroen: Thanks, I have reduced the length of my PATH, unfortunately that also didn't help.

Comment: In tried ProcMon in SafeMode again. The file access was always SUCCESS, but I can see, some registry call's (on curren user path), which  failed. I will look for more details..

Comment: My last comment was wrong. I couln't find any answers with ProcMon. So I did the "nuclear option". After deleting my local profile Visual Studio works fine again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to delete the local user profile. After that, Visual Studio works fine again.